# __unavailable or NS_UNAVAILABLE? NS_ROOT_CLASS or OBJC_ROOT_CLASS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, attributes

If I use Xcode 7.0 or newer using objective-c... which Macro should I use?

- `NS_UNAVAILABLE` or `__unavailable`?
- `DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE` or `__deprecated`?
- `NS_ROOT_CLASS` or `OBJC_ROOT_CLASS`?
- ...

Any general rule to favor __xx or NS_xx?

Comment: can you tell me what NS_UNAVAILABLE mean ?  when I use it ,how does it work? thanks!!!

Comment: @signal [example](http://i.imgur.com/vQn3iNf.png), it generates an error at compile time if you try to use a method marked as NS_UNAVAILABLE. Useful for telling a developer to stop using a given method in a subclass. Note: it doesn't prevent use of the method at runtime if you know indirect means.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule when you want to associate some custom message along with the xCode warning you can use __xx otherwise it is better to use NS_xx.